# How to-do a 2-state button from one image using a picturebox

Tags: c#, picturebox, drawimage, drawrectangle

I am learning C# and I am trying to create a custom button using a picture box.
I inserted an image on the project resources [PNG with 2-state images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUDZX.png).

When the image is shown in the normal state, it shows the top image inside the PNG file and when the mouse enters the picture box area it should show the bottom image on the same PNG but I am doing something wrong because it apparently stays static.

I initiate the constructor with a call for a method I created - BotOK_Normal(); which show the normal state of the button and the code is like this.

```
private void BotOK_Normal()
    {
     private Image BotOK = Resources.BotOK;
     Graphics desenhador = Graphics.FromImage(BotOK);
     desenhador.DrawImage(BotOK, 
                          new Rectangle(0, 0, 90, 36), 
                          new Rectangle(0, 0, 90, 36), 
                          GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
     PB_BotOK.BackgroundImage = BotOK;
    }
```

and the method BotOK_Hover() has a slight change because it has to pick up the bottom image from different coordinates

```
private void BotOK_Hover()
    {
        private Image BotOK = Resources.BotOK;
        Graphics desenhador = Graphics.FromImage(BotOK);
        desenhador.DrawImage(BotOK, 
                             new Rectangle(0, 0, 90, 36), 
                             new Rectangle(0, 36, 90, 36), //y changed
                             GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        PB_BotOK.BackgroundImage = BotOK;
    }
```

I created 2 events associated with the picture box.

```
private void PB_BotOK_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BotOK_Hover();
    }

private void PB_BotOK_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BotOK_Normal();
    }
```

When I hover the mouse inside the picture box nothing changes, what am I doing wrong?

I thank you in advance for any help that you can give me.